# Set of CoffeeScript/JavaScript classes and methods available to rest of Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails 3.2.9. When I add CoffeeScript code to a `.js.coffee` file in the `/app/assets/javascripts` directory, I get the resulting JavaScript in all of my webpages. The problem is all the JavaScript is wrapped in:

```
(function() {
  // my code
}).call(this);
```

So any methods I define are not visible in any other CoffeeScript code I write in other files. What's the proper way to write a set of reusable CoffeeScript classes and methods with Rails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to namespace all your classes. If your application is called "app" then in your initialization code before anything else happens:

```
// Set up the namespace.
window.app = { }
```

and then in all your `.coffee` files:

```
class app.Pancakes
    #...
```

Then you'd have a global namespace and you'd reference everything through that namespace:

```
pancakes = new app.Pancakes
```

Similarly for simple functions:

```
app.where_is = (pancakes, house) -> ...

# And elsewhere...
x = app.where_is(...)
```

There are various ways of setting up and partially hiding the namespace but they're all variations on the above and simple namespacing plays nicely with the Rails asset pipeline.

Comment: Where's the proper place to setup the namespace? application.js? the layout view?

Comment: @at.: anywhere that gets hit first will do. I'm not sure if it will survive in an `application.js` manifest file but I'd guess that it would. You could even throw it in your layout before the rest of your script tags.

Comment: I created a file with an `_` at the beginning, like `_my_stuff.js.coffee`. This way it's loaded before everything else and I can set the `window.app = { }` before the other code that depends on it.

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can define classes within the coffeescript files like this:

```
class this.Person
  constructor: (attr = {}) ->
    ...
```

In that way, the definitions are attached to the global namespace.

Comment: This is something I had been searching for.  I was really annoyed that with Coffeescript I was namespacing everything with `window.name = name`. I generally use Rails 4+ for most applications, so Coffeescript is mostly icing on the cake for me, and this made my day!