# unable to access method in my coffeescript class from outside of class

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

I have this class written in CoffeeScript:

**Notification.js.coffee**

```
class Notification

  display: ->
    @dom.show()

  constructor: (header, messages) ->
    @render(header, messages)
```

Basically, the logic for `render()` function code is to inject HTML into the DOM (but hidden) and `display()` method simply `shows` the DOM element. Now, I have some other class separate to this one where I'm trying to make use of this above class.

**SharerController.js.coffee**

```
class SharerController

  post_story: ->
    # some user action posting something in the app
    notification = new Notification('Header', ['This story has been posted.', 'You can post more. Would you like to?'])
    notification.display()
```

Unfortunately, for some reason - I get

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'notification.display()')`

on the line above where I do `notification.display()`. The same code works absolutely as expected If I write it within the Notification class (where everything gets wrapped into an IIFE). The load order for above files is: Notification.js and then SharerController.js

What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing several things:

1. The `Notification` in your `SharerController` is not the same as the `Notification` you're defining in `Notification.js.coffee`. I think you're picking up Chrome's native [`Notification`](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification) and that doesn't have a `display` method.
2. There is no `@dom` in your `Notification` so your `display` call will fail if you ever manage to call it.
3. There is no `render` method in your `Notification` so your `Notification` constructor will fail due to the `@render` call.

If you're only including a sample of your `Notification` code then (2) and (3) aren't really problems.

CoffeeScript wraps the generated JavaScript in a self-executing function something like this:

```
(function() {
  // JavaScript goes here...
}).call(this);
```

so your `Notification` isn't visible outside your `Notification.js.coffee` file. You can make it globally visible by saying:

```
class window.Notification
  #...
```

or

```
class @Notification
  #...
```

or you could use your own namespace [as in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13392670/479863).

Once you've made your `Notification` available to the rest of your application you can instantiate your own `Notification`, solve your other problems, and finally you'll be calling `display` on something that has a `display` method.

Comment: 1, 2 and 3 were really not problems since I just included some parts of my code. But I figured out the Namespace and scoping was at play here.