# Javascript File Dependencies Not Being Resolved With Manifest Order

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm currently in the process of reorganizing our Javascript/Coffeescript files in our Rails 4 application using [this tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html). Prior to this, because of my ignorance of the asset pipeline, we had most of our code in one giant coffeescript file. The goal is to break this giant file into logical, manageable parts.

Our application uses some general classes to define programing structures like a doubly-linked list. I wanted to put this in a separate file, `app/assets/javascripts/misc_classes.coffee`:

```
### ***********************************###
### ******* General Classes ***********###
### ***********************************###

#single node for doubly linked list
class Node
  constructor: (data) ->
    @data = data
    prev = null
    next = null

#Doubly-linked list class, to be used for front-end destinations
#Details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list
class DoublyList
  constructor: () ->
    @length = 0 #length of the current list
    @head = null #first node of the list
    @tail = null #last node of the list
...
```

The rest of our application code resides in `app/assets/javascripts/custom/trips.coffee`. The code in `trips.coffee` uses the Doubly-linked list class from the other javascript file described above:

```
### ***********************************###
### ****** Custom Site Classes ********###
### ***********************************###

class Trip
  constructor: (id, editable) ->
    @id = id #trip_id
    @title = 'New Trip'
    @cities = 0 #number of citites in trip
    @countries = 0 #number of countries in trip
    @distance = 0 #distance in KM
    @days = 0 #duration of trip in days
    @destinations = new DoublyList()
...
```

From the [Rails Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives), the way to handle this dependency is via the `application.js` manifest file.

> If you need to ensure some particular JavaScript ends up above some other in the concatenated file, **require the prerequisite file first in the manifest**. Note that the family of require directives prevents files from being included twice in the output.

So our `application.js` file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/sortable
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require colorbox-rails
//= require jquery.readyselector
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.externalscript
//= require misc_classes
//= require_tree ./custom/.
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error in the console:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: DoublyList is not defined`

Why is this happening? According to the other posts here, it appears I wrote the manifest file correctly. I can verify both files are included in the sites `<header>` section in the correct order as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, the issue was because of scoping. In production, all of the files would have been joined into `application.js`, but in development, they were all still separate files. I had to add the class to the global namespace for it to work:

```
### ***********************************###
### ******* General Classes ***********###
### ***********************************###

#single node for doubly linked list
class this.Node
  constructor: (data) ->
    @data = data
    prev = null
    next = null

#Doubly-linked list class, to be used for front-end destinations
#Details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list
class this.DoublyList
  constructor: () ->
    @length = 0 #length of the current list
    @head = null #first node of the list
    @tail = null #last node of the list
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392670/set-of-coffeescript-javascript-classes-and-methods-available-to-rest-of-rails-ap)